# How to remove the last comma from tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I remove the comma from each tuple in the list.
I want to make a list of tuples from one list like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,5,4]

l1 = [ ]

l2 =  [ ]

for i in l:

    l1.append (i)
    t = tuple(l1)
    l2.append(t)
    l1 = []

print l2
```

Expected result:

```
[(1), (2), (3), (5), (4)]
```

Real result:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (5,), (4,)]
```

Comment: You can't; that's the syntax for a one-tuple (the comma is the key, not the parentheses). Why would you want to, anyway?

Comment: If you remove the comma it is no longer a tuple

Comment: Type this into the Python shell:  `[(1), (2), (3), (5), (4)]`  and look at what you get -- then you'll see why the question makes no sense!  (Unless you are asking how to print the list of tuples in the confusing way...)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here is one place I've needed to do this: 
dict2 = {key: 'entry' + str(key) for key in itertools.product([1,2], [4,5])}, referencing dict2[1,4] is fine. But dict1 = {key: 'entry' + str(key) for key in itertools.product([1,2,3])}, referencing dict1[2] gives KeyError.  But it will work if the trailing comma is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first element of each tuple in the list displayed (without a comma), you can always manually format the output by using something like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
l1 = []
l2 = []
for i in l:
    l1.append(i)
    t = tuple(l1)
    l2.append(t)
    l1 = []

print '[' + ', '.join('({})'.format(t[0]) for t in l2) + ']'
```

Output:

```
[(1), (2), (3), (5), (4)]
```

BTW, you could also shorten the construction of `l2` to just this:

```
l2 = [tuple([value]) for value in l]
```